# make left div to fill all available space, when right div has fixed width

Tags: css, html

I have on my page 2 divs: one (left) with menu and second (right) with content. Right div must have width of 800px and be horizontally centered. I want left div to fill all remaining space.

I tried setting display of the divs as table-cell or setting float to right and left and putting in left div span element with width:100%, but it didn't work.

Is there any way to make the divs look as I want?

Comment: Very similar questions have been asked before, look under "Related" for various links...

Comment: @cimmanon isn't his question the opposite?

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui Left fixed, right full vs right fixed, left full = same difference.  You reverse the solution, it's not hard.  I'm sure if one searched hard enough, this exact question has already been asked 100 times.

Comment: right div isn't fixed it has margin-left:auto and 
margin-right:auto to make it centered. That's why I didn't find solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
    Menu
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div id="right">
    Content
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left {
    background-color: green; /*for demonstration purposes*/
    float:left;
}

#right{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(document).width();
    var rightDivWidth = $("#right").width();
    var leftDivWidth = width - rightDivWidth;
    $("#left").css("width", leftDivWidth);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/XdF5b/2/)